# How to source a dotenv (.env) file in dash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, dotenv, dash-shell, 12factor

There are a lot of examples here how to source a dotenv file in bash but has anyone one a method that achieves the same with dash (which is the default shell for minimal Debian installations)?

The solution should look like this:

```
$ some foo my-command-using-env-vars
```

e.g.

```
$ env $(cat .env) my-command-using-env-vars
```

And it is important that the solution supports multiline values with spaces like:

```
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nfoo\nbar\baz"
```

and special characters like hash within quotes:

```
SPECIAL="foo#bar"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your problem is not so much that you're using `dash` but that you want to support `\n` escapes. The following works in `dash` and supports `\n` escapes:

```
eval "$(echo $(cat .env))" my-command-using-env-vars
```

That's because unlike in `bash` the built-in `echo` in `dash` supports backslash escapes even without the `-e` option. The following works in both `bash` and `dash`, provided that the non-built-in, system `echo` supports the `-e` option:

```
eval "$(env echo -e $(cat .env))" my-command-using-env-vars
```

Note that both approaches will also handle other backslash escapes (either POSIX or GNU), possibly in a different way than you expect.

Some technical notes:

```
$(cat .env)
```

performs [Field Splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05), converting any newline in file `.env` into spaces.

```
"$(env echo -e ...)"
```

expands backslash escapes regardless of the current shell by invoking `echo -e` via `env`. The double quotes disable field splitting, so that newlines are preserved.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Just for the curious, how exactly will the other backslash escapes be handled in the above cases?

Comment: @BastianVenthur Have a look at the `dash` and `bash` man pages and search for builtin commands. For `env echo`, see the `echo` man page.

Comment: `echo` is fine when using your shell interactively, but you shouldn't use it in scripts which need to be portable, as its behaviour is variable across different systems.  Conversely `printf` is very portable and standardised, so it's good practice to be using that instead.